# Opencart header and Footer Call in Codeigniter Site

Tags: codeigniter, opencart

I have a site in opencart on root and Codeigniter site in sub-directory.
Is there any way to call Opencart Header and Footer in Codeigniter site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well it is possible to call it, you just have to call the tpl files, but variables used there will throw errors and finally it will not work, only if you had static elements only called in your header.tpl and footer.tpl would this work, in the other cases it will not(you would have to include manyy files, and security issues would come up).